# Cannot Publish WebApp or WebJob - 'Media File is Write Protected'

Tags: .net, azure, webjob

I've been publishing my 3 WebApps and 1 WebJob successfully for the past two weeks and all of a sudden I can not longer publish (from Visual Studio) as I get the following error.

> Web deployment task failed. (Failed to delete the auto-swap lock file:
>   The media is write protected.   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_SWAP_FAILED_TO_DELETE_LOCK_FILE.)

I've never this issue. I try to manually create a new WebJob in the Portal and am hitting a generic 'Cannot create WebJob' error with no description at all.

Man, I'm out of ideas.